# How can I create space and a border between an icon and text in a button? HTML email, outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook

[image: Desired button]

This button displays fine on all email clients that I've tested except for out look
I am struggling to put space between the icon and text with a border in between. the only way I have been able to get the height of the text and image to be the same is to put them in the same  tag.
i've tried  and  and between image and text and setting widths to them which hasn't changed anything
Has someone got a better way to do this? Currently in outlook there is no space between the text and icon. Image attached of desired result

```
      <tr>
        <td width="auto" align="center">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
            <tr>
              <td width="auto" align="center" width="20px" height="15px" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none; font-weight: 700; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Montserrat'; font-size: 12px; line-height: 36px; letter-spacing: .1em; vertical-align:middle; text-transform: uppercase;">
                <div  width="20px" height="15px" style="border-right: solid 1px #414141;">
                  <!--[if mso]>
                  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="www.google.com" style="height:50px; v-text-anchor:middle; width:250px;" arcsize="0%" strokecolor="#111111" fillcolor="#111111">
                  <w:anchorlock/>
                  <center style="color:#ffffff; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Montserrat'; font-size:font-size"12px; display: table; border="0"><img src="img/right-arrow-white.png" alt="" border="0" border-right: 1px solid grey; width="17" height="11" style="display: block;"> VIEW OUR PROJECTS</center>
              </v:roundrect>
                <![endif]-->

                  <a href="www.google.com" style="display:inline-block; color:#ffffff; background-color: #111111; text-decoration:none; font-weight: 400; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Montserrat'; font-size: 12px; line-height: 50px; letter-spacing: .1em; vertical-align:middle; height: 50px; width: 58px; mso-hide:all">
                    <img src="img/right-arrow-white.png" width="17px" height="11px" alt="go to link"/>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td width="auto" align="center" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none; font-weight: 400; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Montserrat'; font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px; letter-spacing: .1em; vertical-align:middle; text-transform: uppercase; ">
                <div>
                  <a href="www.google.com" style="display:inline-block; color:#ffffff; background-color: #111111; text-decoration:none; font-weight: 400; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Montserrat'; font-size: 12px; line-height: 50px; letter-spacing: .1em; vertical-align:middle; height: 50px; width: 200px; white-space: nowrap;
                  mso-hide:all;">
                  View our projects
                </a>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
              <tr>
                <td width="auto" align="center">
                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="auto" align="center" width="20px" height="15px" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none; font-weight: 700; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Montserrat'; font-size: 12px; line-height: 36px; letter-spacing: .1em; vertical-align:middle; text-transform: uppercase;">
                        <div>
                          <!--[if mso]>
                          <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="www.google.com.au" style="height:50px; v-text-anchor:middle; width:50px;" arcsize="0%" strokecolor="#111111" fillcolor="#111111">
                          <w:anchorlock/>
                          <center style="color:#ffffff; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Montserrat'; font-size:font-size"12px; vertical-align: middle;"><img src="img/right-arrow-white.png" alt="arrow icon" border-right: 1px solid grey; width="17" height="11" style="display: block;"></center>
                          </v:roundrect>
                          <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="www.google.com.au" style="height:50px; v-text-anchor:middle; width:200px;" arcsize="0%" strokecolor="#111111" fillcolor="#111111">
                      <w:anchorlock/>
                      <center style="color:#ffffff; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Montserrat'; font-size:font-size"12px;>VIEW OUR PROJECTS</center>
                      </v:roundrect>
                        <![endif]-->

                          <a href="www.google.com" style="display:inline-block; color:#ffffff; background-color: #111111; text-decoration:none; font-weight: 400; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Montserrat'; font-size: 12px; line-height: 50px; letter-spacing: .1em; vertical-align:middle; height: 50px; width: 58px; mso-hide:all">
                            <img src="img/right-arrow-white.png" width="17px" height="11px" alt="go to link"/>
                          </a>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td width="auto" align="center" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none; font-weight: 400; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Montserrat'; font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px; letter-spacing: .1em; vertical-align:middle; text-transform: uppercase; ">
                        <div>
                          <a href="www.google.com" style="display:inline-block; color:#f8f8f8; background-color: #111111; text-decoration:none; font-weight: 400; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Montserrat'; font-size: 12px; line-height: 50px; letter-spacing: .1em; vertical-align:middle; height: 50px; width: 200px; white-space: nowrap;
                          mso-hide:all;">
                          View our projects
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
```